# Opening edge in a process. On destroy it doesnt close

Tags: java, process

I'm trying to open and then close a edge webbrowser on windows 10. useing Runtime to exec Edge and returning the process. But when the work is done and the method calls destroy, the browser stays open. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Here is the method i call with a URL to a keycloak.

```
public static Process openURL(String url) {
        
    try {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe\"" + url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Kunde inte starta browser", e);
    }
}
```

Here is the block of code that calls the method and uses destroy after latch.await but the browser stays open. Running the same code with explorer worked fine but explorer is leaving windows so I really want to update the code.

```
try {
    var httpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    var latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            httpSocket.start(PORT, latch);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Kunde inte öppna socket", e);
        }
    }).start();
            
    var browser = WindowsBrowserManager.openURL(authRequestUriBuilder());
    latch.await();
    
    browser.destroy();
    var response = httpSocket.getResponse();
```

Java 17 is used.

Comment: See `browser.descendants()`

Comment: Count of browser.descendants() is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge is a multi-process application, the UI is most likely handled in a separate process. You probably have "startup boost" and/or "Continue running background apps when Microsoft Edge is closed" setting which means these components out-live the process you launch.

Use task manager to check if other `msedge.exe` instances are still running before / after your application and add some logging:

```
 browser.descendants().forEach(ph -> System.out.println("Descendent "+ph));
```

This page describes how to turn off [background apps](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-prevent-new-microsoft-edge-running-background-windows-10) setting.